# pdo_informix fails `make test` after `make`

Tags: php, pdo, informix, rhel6

I've stuck trying to install pdo_informix on rhel6 with php 5.3.3. All is installed, except pdo_informix.so itself. I have such library for php 5.4.4 but it is compiled with API higher than is needed for 5.3.3 , so I was trying to compile from sources. 
And in make test I get this:

```
=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/local/bin/php
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.3.3
ZEND_VERSION: 2.3.0
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux cc-allplus.msk.vtb24.ru 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 1 12:14:02 EST 2015 x86_64
INI actual  : /usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_informix/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :
CWD         : /usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_informix
Extra dirs  :
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================
TIME START 2015-08-20 12:15:53
=====================================================================
FAIL pdo_informix: Connect to database [tests/fvt_001.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows [tests/fvt_002.phpt]
PASS pdo_informix: Connection attempt with wrong user/pwd [tests/fvt_003.phpt]
PASS pdo_informix: Connection attempt with wrong user/pwd [tests/fvt_004.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Get the driver version [tests/fvt_005.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Test error conditions [tests/fvt_006.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Test error conditions [tests/fvt_007.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Test error conditions through non-existent tables [tests/fvt_008.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Test error conditions through faulty SQL [tests/fvt_009.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Update [tests/fvt_010.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Delete [tests/fvt_011.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Select [tests/fvt_012.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Scrollable cursor; retrieve negative row [tests/fvt_013.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: rowCount - insert, delete [tests/fvt_014.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Insert/select clob/blob columns with binding to local variable or stream [tests/fvt_015.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Insert integer by binding an empty string, a NULL, and an integer string to column [tests/fvt_016.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Insert and retrieve a very large file. [tests/fvt_017.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Insert and retrieve a very large clob file. [tests/fvt_017b.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Select LOBs, including null and 0-length [tests/fvt_017c.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Quote a string. [tests/fvt_018.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Get the last inserted serial numbers [tests/fvt_019.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: rollback [tests/fvt_020.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: commit [tests/fvt_021.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: rollback with autocommit off [tests/fvt_022.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: commit with autocommit off [tests/fvt_023.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Change fetch modes. [tests/fvt_024.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Get Column meta data. [tests/fvt_025.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check error code. [tests/fvt_026.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Testing fetchColumn with different modes and options [tests/fvt_027.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: PDOStatement::fetch() [tests/fvt_030.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Tests all Fetch orientations [tests/fvt_031.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check error codes after a failed execution [tests/fvt_032.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check error condition when given null connection parameters [tests/fvt_033.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check error condition when inserting into non-existent table [tests/fvt_034.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check return values from exec [tests/fvt_035.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Test the setting of different options [tests/fvt_036.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Testing the lastInsertID function. [tests/fvt_038.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Get the server info. [tests/fvt_040.phpt]
FAIL pdo_informix: Check the clearing of error codes [tests/fvt_49872.phpt]
=====================================================================
TIME END 2015-08-20 12:15:54

=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :    0
Exts tested     :   28
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests :   39                39
Tests skipped   :    0 (  0.0%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   37 ( 94.9%) ( 94.9%)
Expected fail   :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests passed    :    2 (  5.1%) (  5.1%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :    1 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pdo_informix: Connect to database [tests/fvt_001.phpt]
pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows [tests/fvt_002.phpt]
pdo_informix: Get the driver version [tests/fvt_005.phpt]
pdo_informix: Test error conditions [tests/fvt_006.phpt]
pdo_informix: Test error conditions [tests/fvt_007.phpt]
pdo_informix: Test error conditions through non-existent tables [tests/fvt_008.phpt]
pdo_informix: Test error conditions through faulty SQL [tests/fvt_009.phpt]
pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Update [tests/fvt_010.phpt]
pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Delete [tests/fvt_011.phpt]
pdo_informix: Count number of affected rows - Select [tests/fvt_012.phpt]
pdo_informix: Scrollable cursor; retrieve negative row [tests/fvt_013.phpt]
pdo_informix: rowCount - insert, delete [tests/fvt_014.phpt]
pdo_informix: Insert/select clob/blob columns with binding to local variable or stream [tests/fvt_015.phpt]
pdo_informix: Insert integer by binding an empty string, a NULL, and an integer string to column [tests/fvt_016.phpt]
pdo_informix: Insert and retrieve a very large file. [tests/fvt_017.phpt]
pdo_informix: Insert and retrieve a very large clob file. [tests/fvt_017b.phpt]
pdo_informix: Select LOBs, including null and 0-length [tests/fvt_017c.phpt]
pdo_informix: Quote a string. [tests/fvt_018.phpt]
pdo_informix: Get the last inserted serial numbers [tests/fvt_019.phpt]
pdo_informix: rollback [tests/fvt_020.phpt]
pdo_informix: commit [tests/fvt_021.phpt]
pdo_informix: rollback with autocommit off [tests/fvt_022.phpt]
pdo_informix: commit with autocommit off [tests/fvt_023.phpt]
pdo_informix: Change fetch modes. [tests/fvt_024.phpt]
pdo_informix: Get Column meta data. [tests/fvt_025.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check error code. [tests/fvt_026.phpt]
pdo_informix: Testing fetchColumn with different modes and options [tests/fvt_027.phpt]
pdo_informix: PDOStatement::fetch() [tests/fvt_030.phpt]
pdo_informix: Tests all Fetch orientations [tests/fvt_031.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check error codes after a failed execution [tests/fvt_032.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check error condition when given null connection parameters [tests/fvt_033.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check error condition when inserting into non-existent table [tests/fvt_034.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check return values from exec [tests/fvt_035.phpt]
pdo_informix: Test the setting of different options [tests/fvt_036.phpt]
pdo_informix: Testing the lastInsertID function. [tests/fvt_038.phpt]
pdo_informix: Get the server info. [tests/fvt_040.phpt]
pdo_informix: Check the clearing of error codes [tests/fvt_49872.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

what might be done wrong or would this library work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I searched, that is connected with the absence of the informix test server on local server machine. I didn't need this but still for test cases it is neccessary. I found that out setting up tests again, and anoung all database lib's only sqlLite passed tests, and all others like Mysql, PgSQL, MsSQL, etc. failed or skipped tests.

Right now all my connection works fine with real queries. Hope that would help some one later.